# slanted div top and bottom CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to make the following slanted div. I have nearly achieved the shape below however the bottom is not slanting in the correct direction as my shape below. How can i correct this?

Shape Attached

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net//fgdcq3qp/

**CSS**

```
.slanted {
background: red;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 40vh;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
padding: 20px;
}

.slanted:before {
content: "";
background: red;
height: 40px;
transform: skewY(2deg);
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -1;
}

.slanted:after {
content: "";
background: red;
height: 40px;
transform: skewY(1deg);
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -1;
}

.slanted:before{    
top: -20px;    
}

.slanted:after {
bottom: -30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slanted">
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis et    debitis pariatur perferendis adipisci doloribus aspernatur ea quo illum a.</p>
```

Comment: Your bottom slant needs to be negative degs

Comment: I take it you looked at how Eric Meyer did this back when IE5.5 was popular? http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/demo2.html

Comment: Thanks :) negative value was correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change `skewY` for `.slanted:after` to a negative number and adjust the `height` accordingly (numbers below just an example - adjust to how you want it):

```
.slanted:after {
    content: "";
    background: red;
    height: 80px;
    transform: skewY(-5deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wn4fvb6/)

Answer (score 7):

There is a borders solution too, create a long left one in color and make the top and the bottom transparent.

```css
#trap {
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 500px solid aqua;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="trap"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS3 clip-path property to achieve the desired outcome. Below is a working js fiddle.

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 20%, 100% 85%, 0 100%);
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 20%, 100% 85%, 0 100%);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niteshp27/fgdcq3qp/5/