# How to create lower edge of div slanted using html and css?

Tags: html, css, styling

[image]I have created a div which is normal as a rectangular shape but I need a code to work such that lower edge of div is slanted and likewise other div's below it(which could have slanted edges again).Any help would be appreciated.
This is my code snippet until now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Assignment</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Styling css-->
<style type="text/css">
 .container{
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 25px;
   background-color: black;
   height: 300px;
  }

  #logo{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  #eduhead{
    /*padding-left: 40px;*/
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #3C89AA;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #newref{
    color: white;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
   table{
     width: 100%;
   }
    #signup{
      color:#FFFFFF;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: #3C89AA;
      border-radius: 5px;
   }  
 </style>

 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
  <table>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th id="eduhead"><img src="assets/Group 31.png" id ="logo" 
  alt="img">&emsp;ASSIGNMENT</th>
   <th><a href="" title="Blog" id="newref">Blog</a></th>
   <th><a href="" title="Packages" id="newref">Packages</a></th>
   <th><a href="" title="Login" id="newref">Login</a></th>
   <th><a href="" title="Sign Up" id="signup">Sign Up</a></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>

<!--Including all the JavaScript Files of bootstrap-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js">
</script>

<!--Bootstrap Scrit CDN-->
```

The above is my code including all the CDN for Bootstrap. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you be more precise on the output you want

Comment: I want the div (ending edge) to be slanted in top right direction. @TemaniAfif

Comment: can you share a screenshot? also can you make your code working?

Comment: Yeah sure but can u tell me how can I share the screenshot here?

Comment: when you edit the question you have a button to add an image on the top

Comment: As u can  see the above div is the black one and another div which is below(slanted edge) it's in white background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173694/discussion-between-shreya-rawal-and-temani-afif).

Comment: Do the answers to [slanted div top and bottom CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42003877/1016716) help?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669671/multiple-clip-paths/50669788#50669788

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911876/make-bottom-edge-of-background-colour-another-colour/50911982#50911982

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872981/peculiar-background-css-design/50873167#50873167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2017/design/sloped-edges-with-consistent-angle-in-css/) you can see different approaches to your problem. Below I placed an example, you can adjust precise values. I hope that helps.

```css
.slanted {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0vw,100% 75%,0 100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="slanted">
  Content.
</div>
```